# Set link href based on link text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<a class='special' href='#'>something</a>
<a class='special' href='#'>anything</a>
```

I need to make it with page load:

```
<a class='special' href='something'>something</a>
<a class='special' href='anything'>anything</a>
```

Something like:

```
$('a.special').attr('href', $(this).text());
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either run an `each()` on your collection, that will set the href to the text, but a bit more elegant would be to give a [function as the second parameter for `attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values).

```
$('a.special').attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xNzuc/)

Answer (score 2):

There's an overload of the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method which allows you to pass a function as second parameter:

```
$('a.special').attr('href', function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not what you are expecting here.

`$('a.special').each(function(e) { $(e).attr('href', $(e).text()) });`